# jQuery - Select Element Where Value Equals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a simple way to check a radio option using jQuery based on its initial value at render time.

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="weekly" />Weekly <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="monthly" />Monthly <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="yearly" />Yearly <br />
</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$('input [value="weekly"]').prop("checked", true);
```

I have a JS fiddle set up here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/448712/

The interesting thing is that it works using the native browser document.querySelector but it doesn't seem to work using jQuery. I'd like to stick with jQuery's way of doing this to ensure consistency in the code.

Also, the reason I want to select by value is that the JSON API I'm calling returns an enumerated string type. It would be really annoying if I had to add a unique ID attribute to each radio option and then use a switch case to select the appropriate button based on the enumerated string type.

Comment: `'input [value="weekly"]'` take out the space in the selector.  Just like in css, a space denotes a descendant.

Comment: A simple thing like this is close-able as a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple remove the space between your selector and the attribute:

```
$('input[value="weekly"]').prop("checked", true);
```

```js
$('input[value="weekly"]').prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="weekly" />Weekly <br />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="monthly" />Monthly <br />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="yearly" />Yearly <br />
</form>
```

With space, you are telling jQuery to select elements that have `[value="weekly"]` but are descendants of an `input` element

Comment: It is a strange fate that we should suffer so much fear and doubt over so small a thing... as a space! Blasted. Thanks. That fixed it... I didn't have the space in my querySelector example which accounts for the difference in behaviour. I'll accept the answer once the StackOverflow timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
          $('input[type="radio"][value="weekly"]').prop('checked', true);    

        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="weekly" />Weekly <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="monthly" />Monthly <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="yearly" />Yearly <br />
</form>
```